# Algo trading execution simulation

Tags: high-frequency, algorithmic-trading, limit-order-book, order-execution

Disclaimer: Brand new to high frequency algo trading.

Background:I have tick-by-tick trade data for stock A and I have joined the price and volume data for each trade with the previous snapshot of the first level of the Quotes book table (i.e. BID and ASK snapshots). I thought this would be useful since you can see where the trade was lifted from (i.e. did it hit the bid or lift the offer?).

[image]

Question: Now I would like to simulate a trade execution (while assuming no market impact). In particular, assume I sit at 11:00:55 and my algorithm wants to place a buy order for 20 shares. How exactly would the execution algorithm play out? What's a simple conservative approach? In the case I'm considering, it's ok to wait a bit to execute the trade.

What I'm thinking: Look at the last trade as a reference price and put that price down on the BID side for 20 shares. Now passively wait to see if my BID was crossed for a few ticks, if not, increase the price a bit. Looking for some ideas from an expert or non-nube! Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an exchange simulator to back-test a strategy, or are you asking about the strategy itself?

Comment: @wildbunny exchange simulator

Answer (score 1):

It depends how accurate you need the simulator to be, on the one hand you could simply use the change in bid/ask to gauge whether your simulated order was hit, and on the other you could be modelling things like the the order matching process based on a model for order and trade arrival rates/process.

The simple method is probably not suitable for modelling high frequency trading however as it completely ignores microstructure, queue depth and the presence of informed traders.

Comment: your answer is useful but rather broad. Would you mind detailing the algorithm for the simple case? Maybe you could give a basic example? I realize it's trivial, but I want to make sure we're on the same page. Additionally, could you point me to resources to learn this?

Comment: If you've got your bid at 43.85 and eventually the ask ticks down to <=43.85 you can assume you got filled, same is true in the other direction. If however, the ask moves up and away, you didn't get filled. Some references for the complex version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_matching_system, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_microstructure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_selection, http://market-microstructure.institutlouisbachelier.org/uploads/91_7%20MOALLEMI%202014-12-paris-mm-queue-value.pdf